# Find this conformal mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

Find an explicit one-one conformal mapping that maps the set $$S =\lbrace z\mid z=x+iy, x>0,y>0 \rbrace $$onto  $$V= \lbrace z\mid z=x+iy, 0<x<1 \rbrace$$

**Attempt:** Tried to do it by using composition of a LFT and $1/z$ but did not lead to any where.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert a strip into a sector you have to use the exponential function. Begin with
$$z\mapsto Ce^{cz}$$ and adjust the coefficients properly. I'd say that
$$g(z):=e^{\pi i z/2}=e^{-\pi y/2}\cdot e^{\pi ix/2}$$
maps points with real part $x\in\ ]0,1[\ $ and imaginary part $y\in{\mathbb R}$, i.e. the set $V$, bijectively onto the points $w$ with argument ${\rm Arg}(w)={\pi x\over2}\in \ ]0,{\pi\over2}[\ $ and absolute value $|w|=e^{-\pi y/2}>0$, i.e., onto the set $S$.

Now you want the function $f:=g^{-1}:\ S\to V$. In order to obtain an expression for $f$ we have to solve the equation $w=g(z)$ for $z$. Take the ${\rm Log}$ on both sides:
$${\rm Log}(w)=\log |w| + i {\rm Arg}(w)=-{\pi y\over2} + i{\pi x\over2}={\pi i z\over2}\ .$$
It follows that
$$f(w)=z={2\over\pi i}{\rm Log}(w)\ .$$